# Does single multiple INSERT in MySQL give a high difference in speed when you insert just several rows?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, insert

I have an internet-shop.
User adds some products to the cart so I should insert these rows in the **order_products** table and also in **order_products_components** table which connect each other by several foreign keys.

As you understand User often adds just several products so is it necessary to construct difficult single multiple insert or I have to just use a foreach loop?

Moreover, as I use foreign keys so after each product insert I need to get a row primary key to insert product components to another table.

So can I just use foreach loops to insert several times or it will pretty slow my system?

Comment: It depends on the number of those queries and how well you handle them.

Comment: Kamil is correct. If you are thinking that you're going to see a dramatic increase in volume on your server, then the multiple inserts are a good idea. They can be quite miraculous. But you're right, in small amounts, not such a big deal. It might keep you from having to do a hardware upgrade earlier, if you use multiple inserts.

Answer (score 1):

A Rule of Thumb I have developed over the years:  "Batch" `INSERTs` speed up things by a *factor* of 10.  (Of course, "your mileage may vary".)  An `INSERT` has overhead: it must be sent to the server, parsed, etc.  You get to "diminishing returns" after, say, 100, rows batched together.  At the other end of the spectrum, 5 rows batched together will get you only about 3x speedup.

If you are tight on performance, other things to be concerned with:

`FOREIGN KEYs` have a non-trivial overhead -- each FK constraint is effectively an index lookup in another table.

`innodb_flush_logs_at_trx_commit` -- 1 is good for data integrity, but poor for speed.  (2 is faster)  Putting more things inside a `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` transaction (within reason) mitigates the use of "1".  Each transaction has at least one extra disk hit.  Rule of Thumb:  a commodity disk can handle only 100 hits per second.

"Get the primary key" -- If that is via `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (or equivalent) to get the `AUTO_INCREMENT value, that is essentially free.